# MVC 4 Controller JsonResult

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a question related to my controller in MVC. 
I want to loop inside my JsonResult `GetAfmeldingen` using foreach.

But what I do will not go inside my foreach
here is my code as it looks right now

```
public JsonResult GetJsonAfmeldingen()
{
    if (Functions.HasLoginCookie())
    {
        if (Models.Taken.ActID > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in Talent.Afmelding.Fetch(null, Models.Taken.ActID, null, null))
            {               
                return Json(item.Participant.CompleteName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            return Json("Empty ?? ID = " + Models.Taken.ActID + "", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

In this example, I return a `JsonResult` when the first record in my list hits. I've looked to see if it works but it doesn't. The id is filled but what am I missing here?
I am new to MVC.

Comment: Both `return Json(item.Participant.CompleteName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and `return Json("Empty ?? ID = " + Models.Taken.ActID + "", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` Are not valid Json. You want something like `return Json(new { ID = Models.Taken.ActID }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` This will return a valid Json object.

Comment: Could you post your ajax request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what doesn't work, since you cannot come into the foreach.

```
public JsonResult GetJsonAfmeldingen()
{
    if (Functions.HasLoginCookie())
    {
        //This one is probably not filled.
        if (Models.Taken.ActID > 0)
        {
```

This could be a possible solution:

```
public JsonResult GetJsonAfmeldingen(int actID)
{
    if (Functions.HasLoginCookie())
    {
        //Now it is filled if you post it correctly.
        if (actID > 0)
        {
```

After that try to test it in a smaller scope. Try to have a breakpoint on this line and see if the list is filled.

```
    var listAfmeldingen = Talent.Afmelding.Fetch(null, Models.Taken.ActID, null, null);
    //Breakpoint here
    int count = listAfmeldingen.Count;
    foreach (var item in listAfmeldingen)
    {   
        return Json(item.Participant.CompleteName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Have a look at your routing as well, I use this one:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: If i pass null value instead of the ID than it also not come inside the foreach

Comment: Ok, that would mean, that ActID is not > 0 or there is no login cookie.

Answer (score 2):

This will terminate on the first loop of the foreach, is that what you want?

```
            foreach (var item in Talent.Afmelding.Fetch(null, Models.Taken.ActID, null, null))
            {

                return Json(item.Participant.CompleteName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

Comment: Yes just for now to see if i get the callback with data

Comment: "for this example I return a Jsonresult when the first record in my list hits, just to look if it works but it aint working." Probably, he want this for now, just to test

Comment: Well I don't see you passing any data into the call, so you are parsing it out in one of your other functions through the querystring manually?  Is Model.Taken.ActID>0?

Comment: Yes with ajax Post     return Json("Empty ?? ID = " + Models.Taken.ActID + "", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); will hits

Comment: It almost seems like you want to make your Json call signature something like `public JsonResult GetJsonAfmeldingen(int id)` or `public JsonResult GetJsonAfmeldingen(int actId)`

Comment: Makes that any Difference ? can try

Comment: Well that depends.  I only brought it up because you said you were new to MVC.  If you are passing a parameter on the querystring using the key "actid", then I'm not sure why you have this Models.Taken object just to get it for you rather than just specifying it in the call signature.