# Iterating on a List of objects in javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

From my controller in mvc 4, I request a collection of objects from my model in database using entity framework:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RequestDbObjects()
    {
        List<MyObjectType> objCollection;
        using (DataContext context = new DataContext())
        {
            objCollection= context.MyObjects.Where(o => o.TypeId == 1).OrderBy(k => k.Name).ToList();
        }

        return Json(objCollection);
    }
```

Model:

```
[Table("MyObjects")]
public class MyObjectType
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Type")]
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Type Type{ get; set; }
}

[Table("Type")]
public class Type
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And in the view, using a script:

```
   function recollectData() {         
       $.ajax({
           url: "/Controller/RequestDbObjects/",
           type: 'POST',
           success: function (dataCollection) {
              for(var obj in dataCollection)
              {
                 var value = dataCollection[obj];
              }
           },
           error: function () {
               alert('Cannot retrieve the data');              
           }
       });             
   };
```

In the above controller, first o all I call to the action in the controller which request data from database using entity framework, then from the list of objects returned to the script, I want to iterate on them, and for each of them read some attributes and do some stuff but I do not know how to do it.Ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't you retun a JsonResult instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16686367/mvc-4-controller-jsonresult

Comment: Sincerely, I do not know exactly what to return, maybe it would be the correct.Anyway what I want is to be able to iterate on the collection from the script and access some attributes of each object in the script in order to do some stuff.Ideas?Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Your success handler returns the data. If it is a JSON object you may read it like that:

```
success: function (data) {
    for(var property in data) {
        var value = data[property];
    } 
}
```

If you return an array:

```
success: function (data) {
    for(var i=0; item=data[i]; i++) {

    } 
}
```

Comment: I do not understand at all I guess data in the loop corresponds to the list of objects returned by de controller, am i right?

Comment: Yes, that's  what I mean.

Comment: so you are iterating over, let me say, each object of the list, the value as I understand should be the current object and how to access the attribute of the current object? value.¿?

Comment: With just a dot. I.e. *value.name* for example.

Comment: I do not know why but after returning from the controller, the script is handling an error, so enter in the error option rather than in the success one...

Comment: I mean, that after return from the controller, the script is entering in the error option and then in the complete rather than success and then complete.

Comment: Ok, it goes to the error handler, but the handler accepts an error. Similar like the *data* in the success handler. Check the documentation of ajax method - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I have read the page, maybe it seems like when converting in the controller with Json(mydata) it is not being parsed ok and maybe a malformed json data is originiated so it cause to entering in the error option I guess...but no idea on how to deal with it. I have catched the type of error in the error option like:error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(errorThrown); } and it says: "Internal Server Error"

Comment: What exactly is the response from the server. Simply make the same request via the browser. Is it a valid json data?

Comment: I have update my post with the model.When I request data with entity framework it is returning a list of object whichtype is MyObjectType then they are converted using Json(...).I am not sure if Json(...) is converting the data ok,anything not compatible in the model class with json?the response is http code 500 Internal server error.How to know what is the request to put via the browser?and how I know if it is a valid json data?It is supposed to not be valid json data as it is entering in the script's error, if the conversion Json(...) was correct it should enter in the script's success.

Comment: Hi again! I have discovered that the problem is with my model data. For some reason when Json(...) converts it, it is generating a malformed data. I know because If I check it with another type of model it works and enters in the success, so the problem is the model data but I am wondering why. I do not understand why my data extracted from database using entity framework seems to be not compatible when converting into json using json(...).Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You must return an ActionResult, not a List:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RequestDbObjects()
{
    List<MyObjectType> objCollection;
    using (DataContext context = new DataContext())
    {
        objCollection= context.MyObjects.Where(o => o.TypeId == 1).OrderBy(k => k.Name).ToList();
    }

    return Json(objCollection);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have updated. In fact, I convert the data returned by the query to a list that I store into objCollection, finally I return this object as Json.